# Permission Denied by System -- mkdir node_modules (MacOS - Monterey)

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, node-modules

I can't seem to get around this problem...
I've tried uninstalling node completely and reinstalling, cleaning the npm cache, reinstalling the packages (Angular CLI), running sudo chown -R franfonse ../Programming , but this problem keeps happening.

I try running ng new my-app to create a new project with Angular CLI, and this is what I keep getting:

```
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /Users/franfonse/Desktop/Programming/my-app/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir '/Users/franfonse/Desktop/Programming/my-app/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir '/Users/franfonse/Desktop/Programming/my-app/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/franfonse/Desktop/Programming/my-app/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/franfonse/.npm/_logs/2021-11-10T08_54_24_926Z-debug.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this issue?

I'd appreciate it SO much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command: `npm set prefix 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm'`

If you have already set this value run the above command again after deleting the prefix.

Comment: I have macOS Monterey

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I just installed the latest version of Node.js from the official website. I've been using Home-brew to upgrade and install node, but apparently something was not working through that.

Just install Node.js through official website.

Answer (score 0):

How this worked for me was `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

run this command
sudo npm install -g typescript

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

When you are trying to install any npm package and won't be able to do it in case of permission issues, please check out this video to get the resolution.

Use this command to enable permission on respective npm install locations.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```

The above command will ask you to enter the password, so you need to use the system password which we use to log in to the mac.